# How to make PyCharm pipe python program output through another text processor program

Tags: pycharm

I find no way to have PyCharm pipe process my Python program's output. Specifically, I'm using bunyan ([Python Bunyan](https://github.com/complyue/python-bunyan) ported from [Node Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan)) from my program, it generates JSON log to stderr:

Python Code:

```
logger.info({'nick': 'Duke', 'age': 30, 'expertise': ['Java', 'Javascript', 'Python']},
            'Hi %(nick)s, your expertise recorded!');
```

Raw output:

```
cymp:scratches cyue$ python logging-wander.py 
{"name": "__main__", "expertise": ["Java", "Javascript", "Python"], "nick": "Duke", "age": 30, "time": "2016-08-02T18:16:12Z", "msg": "Hi Duke, your expertise recorded!", "hostname": "cymp.local", "level": 30, "pid": 1418, "v": 0}
```

Pipe processed output:

```
cymp:scratches cyue$ python logging-wander.py 2>&1 | bunyan
[2016-08-02T18:16:15Z]  INFO: __main__/1419 on cymp.local: Hi Duke, your expertise recorded! (nick=Duke, age=30)
    expertise: [
      "Java",
      "Javascript",
      "Python"
    ]
```

The output is piped to bunyan's command line tool for pretty print (there're even colors in terminals, but not shown here).

In WebStorm for js, I can add a local shell script as 'Node interpreter' to do the job, but for PyCharm, their's no 'Add' option for 'Python interpreter' in the 'Run/Debug Configuration' dialog, and it complains `The selected file is not a valid home for PythonSDK` when I try to add the shell script as 'Project Interpreter'.

I wonder any workaround can be used to have my desired result?

Comment: If you need to just color the output, there is a nice plugin for pycharm called [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=pycharm).

Comment: Thanks but the color is of secondary importance to me, I've updated the example to contrast the result. Readability is most wanted while keeping the log data as structured in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I end up with a better (in my sense) solution: craft a startup python stub file `run-module.py` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import runpy

real_stderr = sys.stderr

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    raise Exception('module name is required')

try:
    bi, bo = os.pipe()
    sys.stderr = os.fdopen(bo, 'w')
    subprocess.Popen(['bunyan', '--color'], stdin=bi, stderr=real_stderr)

    modu_name = sys.argv[1]
    sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]  # shift off run-module.py, argv[0] will be replaced by module's __main__
    runpy.run_module(modu_name, alter_sys=True)
except NameError:
    print('sys.path => %r' % sys.path, file=real_stderr)
    raise
except:
    import traceback

    traceback.print_exc(file=real_stderr)
    raise
```

Then run this stub as the script, with real module name as first arg.

<del>Okay, finally I DIY an IntelliJ plugin to solve this. [BunyanConsole Pretty Print](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8526)
while source code on GitHub [BunyanConsole](https://github.com/complyue/BunyanConsole)</del>

[image]