# Format PyCharm's consle output for json logs

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm working on an app whose logs are formatted as JSON with a structure similar to

```
{"level": "INFO", "lineno": 85, "timestamp": "2020-01-01", "message": "Some message"}
```

This format works great in production where the logs are sent to ELK, but as the logs get more complicated it's harder understand them in PyCharm.

I'm looking for a way to format the output of the console (so I don't have to change the format of the logs in the code) to something more readable e.g.

```
2020-01-01 INFO 85 Some message
```

Looking for some solution I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708246/how-to-make-pycharm-pipe-python-program-output-through-another-text-processor-pr/38731286#38731286) option that uses `bunyan` and also a suggestion to use GrepConsole. I didn't manage to make either of them work.

The `bunyan` solution simply didn't work. The logs kept showing as JSON and GrepConsole is great for filtering or highlighting some text, but not for manipulations.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it easier to add a `DEBUG` flag to your code or your environment and format the output before sending it to console if running in debug mode?

Comment: That's a good option but the logging is an external package I don't own. I would have to encapsulate it and replace the usages across all of the app. I'll do it if there aren't any better options

Answer (score 1):

Since python3.11, the new stack trace gets even more complex when using json-formatter.

However, Pycharm has added a small "soft-wrap" option which will expand the json to full size:

This:
[image]

Turns into this:
[image]

Hope it can help.